# Removing characters if it appears more than once

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string given by user. After the user entry i want the character '`-`' to appear only once even if appears twice or more.

`DF--JKIL-L` should be `DF-JKIL-L`

```
`DF-----JK-L-` should be `DF-JK-L-`
```

Comment: I retagged your post as regex, I'm assuming that's what you're looking for (not regedit)?

Comment: yeah thanks i was about to edit that one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple regular expression should do the trick:

```
string originalString = "DF-----JK-L-";
string replacedString = Regex.Replace(originalString, "-+", "-");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Split` with option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, then `Join` again:

```
 var result = string.Join("-", 
              input.Split(new[] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```